# Declared list raises NoneType exception

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, nonetype

I have a snippet from someone else's python module that is raising an exception (`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`). The snippet is:

```
def generateFragments(self):
    tr = self.deviceTransform()
    if tr is None:
        return
    pts = np.empty((2,len(self.data['x'])))
    pts[0] = self.data['x']
    pts[1] = self.data['y']
    pts = fn.transformCoordinates(tr, pts)
    self.fragments = []
    pts = np.clip(pts, -2**30, 2**30) ## prevent Qt segmentation fault.
                                      ## Still won't be able to render correctly, though.
    for i in xrange(len(self.data)):
        rec = self.data[i]
        pos = QtCore.QPointF(pts[0,i], pts[1,i])
        x,y,w,h = rec['fragCoords']
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(y, x, h, w)
        self.fragments.append(QtGui.QPainter.PixmapFragment.create(pos, rect))
```

And the exception message is:

```
[14:35:59]  Ignored exception:

    |==============================>>
    |  Traceback (most recent call last):
    |    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyqtgraph/debug.py", line 35, in w
    |      func(*args, **kwds)
    |    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ScatterPlotItem.py", line 714, in paint
    |      self.generateFragments()
    |    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/ScatterPlotItem.py", line 685, in generateFragments
    |      self.fragments.append(QtGui.QPainter.PixmapFragment.create(pos, rect))
    |  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
    |  
    |==============================<<
```

This isn't a "fix my error" question but a "how is this possible" question. A couple of lines above, `self.fragments` is declared as an empty list. From that point onwards, the only modification of `self.fragments` is to call `append()`. How could the type have possibly changed? Is there a possible failure in the append operation that might change the type of the list to `NoneType`?

Comment: Is `self.data` a property? If so, there could be something in that function that sets `self.fragments` to `None`. I don't see anything else that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, `self.data` is a `numpy` array

Comment: Does the exception occur on the very first iteration?

Comment: No, it always happens somewhere within the iteration of `self.data` and always exits when it happens (i.e. it may happen on 25/60 and stop at 25, next failure might be on iteration 0/111, etc)

Comment: Is there anything that runs concurrently with this function? The affected list is an instance attribute rather than a local variable, so other code could easily set it to `None`. Try patching the code to build the list as a local variable, and only assign it to `self.fragments` once the loop has completed.

Comment: Are you showing all code in the loop `for i in xrange(len(self.data)):`? Or,  are there more lines in this loop?

Comment: Yeah, that's the entire loop (and the entire function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 possibilities coming to my mind are:

- concurrency (as per @ekhumoro's comment).
- the class is defining a `__getattribute__` method that short circuits the usual attribute retrieval mechanism.